# Array of polymorphic unique_ptr

Tags: c++

Using unique pointers, we can write

```
class A{};
class B: public A{};
class C: public A{};
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> myArray;
//
f()
{
    std::unique_ptr<B> pB {new B()};
    std::unique_ptr<C> pC {new C()};
    myArray.push_back(std::move(pB));
    myArray.push_back(std::move(pC));
    // nice! now I can use the interface of A without
    // worrying about its subclasses.
}
```

However, if classes `B` and `C` need to have their own type-dependent custom deleter:

```
class A{};
class B: public A{};
class C: public A{};

template<class T>
struct custom_deleter
{ // roughly the same implementation as std::default_deleter
    void operator()(T* p)
    {
        CustomFree(p);
    }
};
//
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> myArray; 
//
f()
{
    std::unique_ptr<B, custom_deleter<B>> pB {CustomAlloc(B())};
    std::unique_ptr<C, custom_deleter<C>> pC {CustomAlloc(C())};
    myArray.push_back(std::move(pB)); // error: can't convert to default deleter
    myArray.push_back(std::move(pC)); // item dito
}
```

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Is there an reason the custom deletion cannot go in the destructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example has undefined behavior because `A` doesn't have a `virtual` destructor. `unique_ptr`'s default deleter, [`std::default_delete`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete) is stateless, so a `unique_ptr<A>` will always call `delete p;`, where the static type of `p` is `A*`.

Your code compiles because the `default_delete<T>` copy constructor can accept another `default_delete<U>` instance as long as `U*` is implicitly convertible to `T*`, which it is in this case. However, polymorphic deletion of the derived class object through base class pointer, when the base class destructor is not `virtual` is undefined behavior.

---

The second problem of custom deleters for each type can be solved by supplying a custom deleter that is a lambda which first casts the argument to the appropriate type before passing it on to that object's deleter.

For instance,

```
template<typename T>
void CustomDeleter(T *t)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    delete t;
}

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A, void(*)(A *)>> myArray;

myArray.push_back(
    std::unique_ptr<A, void(*)(A *)>(new A(), [](A *a){ 
        CustomDeleter(a); }));
myArray.push_back(
    std::unique_ptr<A, void(*)(A *)>(new B(), [](A *a){ 
        CustomDeleter(static_cast<B*>(a)); }));
myArray.push_back(
    std::unique_ptr<A, void(*)(A *)>(new C(), [](A *a){ 
        CustomDeleter(static_cast<C*>(a)); }));
```

When the `vector` goes out of scope, this prints:

```
void CustomDeleter(T*) [with T = A]
void CustomDeleter(T*) [with T = B]
void CustomDeleter(T*) [with T = C]
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a029d8ac57e65d2)

Answer (score 1):

No, the type of the custom deleter is a template parameter to `std::unique_ptr`. Your easiest solution would be to add a member variable to the custom deleter:

```
struct custom_deleter
{
    int m_kind;
    custom_deleter(int kind)
    {
        m_kind = kind;
    }
    void operator()(A* p)
    {
        switch (m_kind)
        {
            case 0:
                CustomFree0(p);
                break;
            case 1:
                CustomFree1(p);
                break;
            //...
        }
    }
};
```

And then make `CustomAlloc` build the appropriate `custom_deleter` and pass it to the constructor of `std::unique_ptr<A, custom_deleter>` as second parameter.